# How can I fix the slow freezing text messaging app on my MyTouch 3G Slide?

Tags: sms, htc-mytouch-3g-slide

I have a MyTouch 3G Slide w/ Android 2.2 and am having issues with the text messaging freezing up all the time and running incredibly slow. If I try to delete all the texts, the messaging application will continue to show the circular thinking pattern for over an hour and never delete all the texts. I ended up having to delete 3 texts at a time and waiting 5 minutes each time.... It's really frustrating... I have tried handcent sms and have the same issues with it

1) Is there a fix for slow/freezing text messaging other than factory reset?

2) Is there an app that deletes text messages over 2 weeks old?

3) Is there a better text messaging app than the onboard android messaging application for android 2.1 with better reliability, ease of use, and speed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Handcent SMS](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.handcent.nextsms) is the most oft-recommended SMS replacement app on this site, so it's probably good to try.  If you have no issues with it, then I would assume it's just a buggy SMS app that you have and not a deeper problem.

If you don't mind losing **all** your messages you could try going to `Settings -> Applications -> Manage applications`, finding the SMS app ("Messaging" or similar), and clearing the data for it. There may also be something like "Messaging Storage" that you need to clear.

I don't know of any app that will improve performance of the existing app, and replacing a messaging app can be tricky.  I'd recommend a custom ROM that has had some of these bugs worked out.  [This XDA topic](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=924793) has a good overview of ROMs for your device.

Comment: @MatthewRead, I have tried Handcent SMS and have the same issues with it. I heard that Handcent is buggier than the onboard froyo messaging application and is not recommended by a T-Mobile Tech Support Rep.

Comment: Everyone at T-Mobile is clueless.  But if Handcent has the same issues for you then I'm guessing it's a system problem.  Try a factory reset as per the other question.

Comment: @MatthewRead, How is clearing the SMS data via Manage applications Messaging" and "Messaging Storage" not a good answer to this question if you can't delete your texts from the application itself?

Comment: @Brian It doesn't answer these questions: "Is there an app that deletes text messages over 2 weeks old, a better text message app, or a fix for this issue?"  However if you don't mind deleting **all** messages, I've amended this answer to include the option of clearing the data.

Comment: @MatthewRead, it answers the "fix for this issue" question.  I reworded the questions so that they are clearer. Are there any apps to improve messaging performance?

Comment: OK, cool.  Updated my answer again.

Comment: Do you think it's worth upgrading to the G2 to fix performance issues?

Answer (score 2):

I know this is late, but I have the same kind of phone, and came across the same problem. Honestly, if you have that many messages and still want to delete them, the best way to do so is to set the screen fade out to never, plug it into the charger, and delete the messages while you're sleeping. By the time you wake up the loading circle will be gone, along with all the messages you deleted. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

Late reply, but I just experienced the same thing and used a different approach to fix this problem which may work for others.  I'm not sure what caused this issue--never really looked at my Texting settings before.  But below is what worked for me when restarting, and deleting data did nothing for me.

I went to Running Applications, found the Texting application (mine was Multi-touch keyboard), selected it, went to settings, changed the input method to "Swype", then closed out.  This stopped the keyboard from locking whenever I went to input txt into any application.